# Shard Recovery Management

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have tried code found in the following link

[Recovery Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-database-recovery-manager)

However when I execute  rm.ResolveMappingDifferences(g, MappingDifferenceResolution.KeepShardMapping);

I recieve an error

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.ShardManagementException' occurred in Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client.dll

Additional information: Store Error: Login failed for user 'TestShardAdmin'.. The error occurred while attempting to perform the underlying storage operation during 'Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.StoreException: Error occurred while performing store operation. See the inner SqlException for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'TestShardAdmin'.

TestShardAdmin has db_owner privilege over the shard db as well as the Shard Manager DB. The same user is used to retrieve the RecoveryManager for the particular shard map which it has no trouble doing so I am not sure where the issue is.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just to verify, TestShardAdmin has db_owner privilege on the shard map manager database?

Comment: Thanks - yes  the TestShardAdmin has db_owner privilege on the shard map manager database